# Open URL with postfix from variable - JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

$dash = www.dashboard.com

$name = My Test Panel

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="button" onclick="window.open('$dash + $Name')"/>

<script>onclick="window.open(this.href,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=600,left=10,top=10,,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); return false;"</script>
```

When I click the button I want the following URL to open

**www.dashboard.com/My%20Test%20Panel**

My above code is no good :(

Answer (score 1):

You mistook with letter `'`
You can use this

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="button" onclick="window.open($dash + $name)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the strings together:

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="button" onclick="window.open(`${$dash}${$name}`)"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it dont open anything! at least with the '     ' in place it opens.

Comment: Oh my bad @LukeToss, fixed now, any better?